# Facebook login with Parse client site, use user object with Express js

Tags: javascript, express, parse-platform, facebook-javascript-sdk

I am trying to create a login procedure with the Parse and Facebook Javascript SDK. The authentication works without a problem on the client side, but I need to access the user object (created by Parse SDK) on the server side too. How can I do this the most elegant way? I thought when I log in into Facebook via Parse a cookie is set and so I can access the user object from the server. Or should I do the login process server side? Any recommendations?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm facing the same problem. Turns out that you can use either server-side auth or client-side auth. You cannot mix-and-match the two. Have a look at their [official blog post about sessions](http://blog.parse.com/announcements/new-cloud-modules-for-images-and-users/).

```
var parseExpressCookieSession = require('parse-express-cookie-session');

// In your middleware setup...
app.use(express.cookieParser('YOUR_SIGNING_SECRET'));
app.use(parseExpressCookieSession({ cookie: { maxAge: 3600000 } }));

// Making a "login" endpoint is SOOOOOOOO easy.
app.post("/login", function(req, res) {
  Parse.User.logIn(req.body.username, req.body.password).then(function() {
    // Login succeeded, redirect to homepage.
    // parseExpressCookieSession will automatically set cookie.
    res.redirect('/');
  },
  function(error) {
    // Login failed, redirect back to login form.
    res.redirect("/login");
  });
});
```

Also, I came across this when digging through the doc:

> You can add Parse.User authentication and session management to your
>   Express app using the parseExpressCookieSession middleware. You just
>   need to call Parse.User.logIn() in Cloud Code, and this middleware
>   will automatically manage the user session for you.
>
> You can use a web form to ask for the user's login credentials, and
>   log in the user in Cloud Code when you receive data from this form.
>   After you call Parse.User.logIn(), this middleware will automatically
>   set a cookie in the user's browser. During subsequent HTTP requests
>   from the same browser, this middleware will use this cookie to
>   automatically set the current user in Cloud Code.
>   ...
>
> When you work with user data, you should use HTTPS whenever possible.
>   To protect your app and your users, the parseExpressCookieSession
>   middleware requires you to use HTTPS. For your convenience, we also
>   provide a parseExpressHttpsRedirect middleware for redirecting all
>   HTTP requests to HTTPS.